# How can I determine the best data structure/implementation for my dataset?

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

Preface: I'm a self-taught coder, so a lot of my knowledge is limited to my research. I'm hoping to have other opinions as I want to build things right the first time. I need help with determining an appropriate solution and how to implement the solution.

---

I'm looking to build a least cost alternative model (essentially a shortest path) for delivering between locations (`nodes`), based on different modes of transportation (`vehicles`) and the different roads taken (`paths`). Another consideration is the product price (`value`) to determine the least cost path.

Here are my important data items:

- `nodes`: cities where the product will travel to and from.
- `paths`: roads have different costs, depending on the road.
- `vehicles`: varying vehicles have differing rental costs when transporting (motorbike, car, truck). Note that the cost of a vehicle is not constant, it is highly dependent on the to/from nodes. For example, using a car to go from city A to city B will have a different cost than using a car to go from city B to A or city A to city C.
- `value`: Product value. Again, a product's value is highly dependent on its destination node. The same product can have a different value at City A, B or C.

---

## Problem Statement

How to setup data structure to best determine where the least cost path would be to get a product from one location to every other location.

## Possible Solutions

From my research, I believe a **weighted graph** data structure would be most suitable for my situation in combination with **dijkstra's** algorithm. I believe breaking the problem down simpler would be essential, to first create a simple weighted graph of only `nodes` and `paths`.

From there, adding the `vehicle` cost and the product `value` considerations afterwards. Perhaps just adding the two values as a cost to "visit" a `node`? (aka incorporate it into the `path` cost?)

Thoughts on my current solution? Other considerations I overlooked? Perhaps a better solution?

## Implementation

I'd love to be able to build this within Excel VBA (as that is how I learned how to code) and Excel is what I use for my tools. Would VBA be too limited in this task? How else can I incorporate my analysis with Excel with another language?

Answer (score 0):

Try the book Practical Management Science by Winston & Albright and check out the chapter on Operations Management - lots of models explained in there from the simple onwards. Available online as a pdf : http://ingenieria-industrial.net/downloads/practicalmanagementscience.pdf

Answer (score 0):

VBA is more a scripting language than a full-fledged one, though one may contend that the underlying framework is .NET. Why don't you give a shot at C++ or Java? If you intuitively understand the data structure and the algorithm, then it'll be a breeze coding in these. Chapter 4 of Algorithms by Sedgewick and Wayne has a beautiful explanation of Shortest Paths. You may also consider studying Bellman-Ford algorithm if you foresee any negative weight cycles on a vertex.